# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un parametro de una query por un metodo?

Tags: c#, sql, imagen, datagrid

Necesito pasar por un método el parametro "imagen" conseguido en la query por un método, para poder enseñar la foto en un dataGrid.

```
    var select = "SELECT nombrePro as Producto, descPro as Descripción, categoriaPro as Categoria, precioPro as Precio, stockPro as Stock, image as Imagen FROM Productos WHERE categoriaPro='Multimedia' AND stockPro>0";
    Helper helperclass = new Helper();
    var c = new SqlConnection(helperclass.getConnectionDB(@"(localdb)\BrunsdDB1", "BrunsdDB1")); // Your Connection String here

    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);


    var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);


    var ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

El método:

```
     public static BitmapImage RecogerImagen(byte[] bytesImagen)
 {
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytesImagen);
bitmapImage.EndInit();

return bitmapImage;}
```

No se como incluir en el datagrid la imagen y que se vea, ni como poder pasar el método por esa columna [5] que es donde deberia de ir las imagenes.

Comment: En esencia, tu lo q quieres es que te salga una imagen en una celda de un datagridview

Comment: Claro claro, lo que no consigo hacerlo

Comment: Y esa imagen esta guardada en una base de datos?

Comment: siii, en bytes, lo pillo con la query, lo que pasa es que no se como pasarle mi metodo a el parametro de solo "imagen"